# If $A^2=I$, how would you prove that the only eigenvalues that $A$ has are 1 and -1, assuming $A \ne I$ and $A \ne -I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To approach to this problem, I look at the equation $(\lambda I -A)x=0 \implies A=\lambda I $ (Not sure if it's right). So if $\lambda$ is 1, that contradicts the assumption. What is wrong here? And by the way, is A diagonalizable here?

Comment: You might use the word "eigenvalue" somewhere in your question.

Comment: $(\lambda I -A)x=0 \implies A=\lambda I$ – That part is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Take $v \neq 0$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. Apply $A$ again to get $v = \lambda^2 v$. Then $\lambda^2 = 1$. So?

Comment: But by appling A to both side, you assume that A=$\lambda I$ so that $\lambda \lambda I$ = $\lambda^2$? Sorry I have a poor sense of property.

Comment: All the steps are: $$Av = \lambda v \implies A^2v = A(\lambda v) \implies Iv = \lambda Av \implies v = \lambda^2v.$$Ok?

Answer (score 1):

It is not right, in matrix spaces you have not the property $Ax=Bx\implies A=B$ (take for example $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$). But you can note that $$P=X^2-1=(X+1)(X-1)$$ is such that $P(A)=0$ and then the roots $1$ and $-1$ will be the only eigenvalues possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

By definition,

$$ A v = \lambda v$$.

Now consider the following,

$$ 1 v = I v = AA v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda(Av) = \lambda(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v,$$

this leads to,

$$ (1-\lambda^2)v = 0 $$

which means that either $v$ is the zero vector or the scalar $1-\lambda^2=0$. Since $v$ is an eigenvector it is not allowed to be the zero vector by definition, leaving us with the equation $1-\lambda^2=0$. There are only two solutions to this last equation $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks

Comment: @1412, no problem :).